# What kind of printing system used by elementary OS?

Tags: printer, user-interface

What kind of printing system used by elementary OS?I used Manjaro Linux on some of my computers on the local network, and Manjaro used CUPS as printing system, without GUI, configure through web-page localhost:631.I want install perfect elementary OS GUI for printers.
Sorry for bad english :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have CUPS as printing system, however you have a nice GUI to configure it in the *Switchboard* (System Settings) as well:

[image]